# Como poner dos columnas en html y bootstrap 5

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-5

¿Cómo hago para que una tabla quede en el costado de mi formulario?

Se poco y nada sobre este lenguaje, pero no se como ponerlo en el costado.

Se que utiliza 12 columnas, las tengo que dividir segun quiero, pero la idea es que sea menos el formulario y mas la grilla.

Estoy utilizando **bootstrap 5**.

Este es mi código

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <form method="POST" id="formulario" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">

          <label for="equipo">Ingrese equipo</label>
          <input type="text" name="equipo" id="equipo" class="form-control">
          <br />
          <input type="submit" name="action" id="action" class="btn btn primary" value="Buscar">
          <br /> <br />
          <label for="tipo">Ingrese tipo</label>
          <input type="text" name="tipo" id="tipo" class="form-control">
          <br />

          <label for="marca">Ingrese marca</label>
          <input type="text" name="marca" id="marca" class="form-control">
          <br />

          <label for="modelo">Ingrese modelo</label>
          <input type="text" name="modelo" id="modelo" class="form-control">
          <br /> <br />
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
          <input type="hidden" name="id_equipo" id="id_equipo">
          <input type="hidden" name="operacion" id="operacion">
          <input type="submit" name="action" id="action" class="btn btn-success" value="Agregar">
          <input type="submit" name="action" id="action" class="btn btn-warning" value="Modificar">
        </div>

      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Indica en tu pregunta que version del bootstrap estas usando (entiendo que usas una, porque sus clases son las mismas)

Comment: Estoy utilizando bootstrap 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap utiliza un sistema de 12 columnas

en una columna de 6 podes poner el formulario, y en otra columna de 6 la tabla, pero estas columnas las podes dividir como quieras (siempre que existan 12 en total)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
            <form method="POST" id="formulario" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-body">
          
                    <label for="equipo">Ingrese equipo</label>
                    <input type="text" name="equipo" id="equipo" class="form-control">
                    <br />
                    <input type="submit" name="action" id="action" class="btn btn primary" value="Buscar">
                    <br /> <br />
                    <label for="tipo">Ingrese tipo</label>
                    <input type="text" name="tipo" id="tipo" class="form-control">
                    <br />
          
                    <label for="marca">Ingrese marca</label>
                    <input type="text" name="marca" id="marca" class="form-control">
                    <br />
          
                    <label for="modelo">Ingrese modelo</label>
                    <input type="text" name="modelo" id="modelo" class="form-control">
                    <br /> <br />
                  </div>
          
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id_equipo" id="id_equipo">
                    <input type="hidden" name="operacion" id="operacion">
                    <input type="submit" name="action" id="action" class="btn btn-success" value="Agregar">
                    <input type="submit" name="action" id="action" class="btn btn-warning" value="Modificar">
                  </div>
          
                </div>
              </form>
        </div>

        <div class="col-8">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    <th scope="col">Tipo</th>
                    <th scope="col">Marca</th>
                    <th scope="col">Modelo</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row">2</th>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row">3</th>
                    <td colspan="2"></td>
                    <td></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Supongo que te refieres a algo así:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

    <head>
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>

    <body>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-4">
            <form method="POST" id="formulario" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="equipo">Ingrese equipo</label>
                <input type="text" name="equipo" id="equipo" class="form-control">
              </div>
              <div class="mb-3">
                <input type="submit" name="action" id="action" class="btn btn-primary" value="Buscar">
              </div>
              <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="tipo">Ingrese tipo</label>
                <input type="text" name="tipo" id="tipo" class="form-control">
              </div>
              <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="marca">Ingrese marca</label>
                <input type="text" name="marca" id="marca" class="form-control">
              </div>
              <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="modelo">Ingrese modelo</label>
                <input type="text" name="modelo" id="modelo" class="form-control"></div>
              <div class="mb-3">
                <input type="hidden" name="id_equipo" id="id_equipo">
                <input type="hidden" name="operacion" id="operacion">
                <input type="submit" name="action" id="action1" class="btn btn-success" value="Agregar">
                <input type="submit" name="action" id="action2" class="btn btn-warning" value="Modificar">
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="col-8">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Equipo</th>
                  <th>Tipo</th>
                  <th>Marca</th>
                  <th>Modelo</th>
                  <th>Acciones</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>Servidor Oficina</td>
                  <td>Torre</td>
                  <td>HP</td>
                  <td>Server</td>
                  <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary me-2">
                      Editar
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">
                      Eliminar
                    </button></td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>

  </html>
```

Si revisas bien el código verás que he hecho muchos cambios, los cuales te detallo mejor a continuación:

1. He eliminado todas las clases donde usabas cosas de los **modales**. Su funcionalidad no es poner un marco simplemente, para eso esta la clase **card** que te recomiendo aprender.
2. He eliminado los `<br />` y he aplicado el estilo mb-3 (margin-bottom 3) porque en bootstrap puedes usar clases para practicamente todo, tambien espaciado.
3. He arreglado el boton Buscar, pues tenias un estilo `btn primary` mal puesto, es `btn-primary`.
4. He cambiado los `id="action"` repetidos. Los **id** no deben repetirse. Los he renombrado a `action1` y `action2`.
5. He agregado la segunda columna que pedias, pues tan solo usabas una de este modo: `<div class="col-md-4">`, por lo tanto, he puesto al mismo nivel otra con valor de 8: `<div class="col-8">` para completar las 12 columnas del grid de bootstrap.
6. Dentro de esa segunda columna he creado una tabla de ejemplo.

**Nota:** Una aclaración respecto a las 12 columnas. No es que tengas 12 columnas tan solo en todo el ancho de la página, sino que las tienes dentro de cada elemento con la clase `row` (normalmente son `div`).  Y esos `<div class="row">` pueden ir dentro de cualquier columna previa creada con la clase `col-` (por ejemplo `<div class="col-4">`), y así sucesivamente, por lo tanto puedes reparticionarlas tambien por dentro tantas veces como quieras (bueno, lo que se pueda dado el ancho del dispositivo que tengas, pues bootstrap se da cuenta de la resolución del dispositivo y puede terminar apilando columnas si no caben). Es decir, pueden anidarse.

Answer (score 2):

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">

    <form method="POST" id="formulario" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">

          <label for="equipo">Ingrese equipo</label>
          <input type="text" name="equipo" id="equipo" class="form-control">
          <br />
          <input type="submit" name="action" id="action" class="btn btn primary" value="Buscar">
          <br /> <br />
          <label for="tipo">Ingrese tipo</label>
          <input type="text" name="tipo" id="tipo" class="form-control">
          <br />

          <label for="marca">Ingrese marca</label>
          <input type="text" name="marca" id="marca" class="form-control">
          <br />

          <label for="modelo">Ingrese modelo</label>
          <input type="text" name="modelo" id="modelo" class="form-control">
          <br /> <br />
       </div> <!--final de una columna--->

        <div class="col-md-8"
          <!---- en este espacio vas a colocar el codigo de tu tabla---->
        </div><!--final de la otra columna--->


        <div class="modal-footer">
          <input type="hidden" name="id_equipo" id="id_equipo">
          <input type="hidden" name="operacion" id="operacion">
          <input type="submit" name="action" id="action" class="btn btn-success" value="Agregar">
          <input type="submit" name="action" id="action" class="btn btn-warning" value="Modificar">
        </div>

      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

por otra parte, el tamaño de las columnas lo va a determinar el numero que coloque en tu clase del div "col-md-4" o "col-md-8". La suma entre los números que presentan las dos clases de los div no deben ser superior a 12. Por favor, leer la documentacion de [bootstrap en el apartado grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/) para mayor informacion